# Prove $m_1m_2\ldots m_k$ and $m_{k + 1}$ are relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_k, m_{k + 1}$ with $m_i > 0 \in \mathbb Z $ are pairwise relatively prime, then $m_1m_2\ldots m_k$ and $m_{k + 1}$ are relatively prime.

Let $n = m_1m_2\ldots m_k$ and assume that $\gcd(n, m_{k + 1}) \neq 1.$ Then there's some prime $p$ such that $p \mid n$ and $p \mid m_{k + 1}$. Since $p \mid n$, we have that $p \mid m_i.$ But we said $\gcd (m_i, m_{k + 1}) = 1.$ Contradiction.

Is it acceptable as a proof?

Comment: @ Quang Hoang, if you answer this post with that same comment, I'll choose your answer just to say thank you.

Comment: $‎\exists i$ such that. $p \mid m_i.$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say "Since $p\mid n$, we have that $p\mid m_i$ *for some* $i$".

Comment: Seems to me this should be a comment, not an answer, as it just suggests an improved logic/wording for OP's already correct answer.